# Using Ansible's rescue option in a roles-based playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook which is basically comprised of roles:

```
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: True
  environment:
    http_proxy: "{{ lookup('env','http_proxy') }}"
    https_proxy: "{{ lookup('env','https_proxy') }}"
  roles:
      - { role: watchdog, status: 'disabled' }
      - { role: use-my-version }
      - { role: services-action, action: 'stopped', acme_services: "{{stop_services_before_install}}", become: yes }
      ... more roles being called ...
      - { role: watchdog, status: 'enabled' }
```

Now, it's possible that one of the roles will fail, which means we won't get to the watchdog-enabled call. I want the watchdog to be enabled even if the playbook fails at any point. I saw `rescue`, but that's for a `block`, but that is only for `task`s. How would you suggest going about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add to the role that you are interested to be executed a tag:

```yaml
{ role: watchdog, status: 'enabled', tags: 'enable_watchdog' }
```

and execute again the playbook with that tag if the first execution failed (to the execution add `-t enable_watchdog`. Avoid to overwrite the logs of the execution of the playbooks, so you'll have a way to troubleshoot the original issue.